# Passing TextArea to php comes out as one line string

Tags: php, html, text, ascii

I'm at a bit of a loss on how to get this to work, as not really a PHP person.

basically in my form, I have a TextArea in my HTML, where a user will paste in a TraceRoute from their command line. This then get's passed to my PHP form (where it's turned into xml...this is unimportant).

However, the tracert is coming out as one single lined string, as opposed to individual lines. This makes it very difficult to read.

So I need a way for the traceroute to be displayed exatly as it is in the TextArea box.

Here is my html code (submit.html)

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="convert2xml.php" method="post">
Traceroute:
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="Traceroute"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my PHP file which handles the data (convert2xml.php).

```
<html>
<body>
&#60;Information&#62;
Traceroute output:
<br>
<?php echo $_POST["Traceroute"]; ?> &#60;/Information&#62;
<br>
```

As you can see the < and > have been replaced with the html codes, this is what turns it into a nice XML layout (in this case it is in a xml tag called Information).

An example input would be (i've redacted some of the IP's and domains):

```
    C:\Users\******>tracert 8.8.8.8

    Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
    over a maximum of 30 hops:

      1     1 ms     3 ms     1 ms  192.168.0.1
      2    12 ms    12 ms     8 ms  **.**.**.**
      3     9 ms    12 ms     9 ms  **.**.**.**
      4    13 ms    13 ms    13 ms  example-doman.name [**.**.**.**]
      5    15 ms    15 ms    14 ms  example-doman.name [**.**.**.**]
      6    12 ms    14 ms    13 ms  **.**.**.**
      7    14 ms    13 ms    16 ms  **.**.**.**
      8    11 ms    19 ms    15 ms  google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]

    Trace complete.
```

But what i am getting is one continous string:

```
<Information>C:\Users\******>tracert 8.8.8.8 Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8] over a maximum of 30 hops: 1 1 ms 3 ms 1 ms 192.168.0.1 2 12 ms 12 ms 8 ms **.**.**.** 3 9 ms 12 ms 9 ms **.**.**.** 4 13 ms 13 ms 13 ms example-doman.name [**.**.**.**] 5 15 ms 15 ms 14 ms example-doman.name [**.**.**.**] 6 12 ms 14 ms 13 ms **.**.**.** 7 14 ms 13 ms 16 ms **.**.**.** 8 11 ms 19 ms 15 ms google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8] Trace complete. </Information>
```

I've looked into nl2br, but this doesn't help me, as i would have to input the "\n" manually at the end of the traceroute line to get it to work.

The only thing i can think of, would be a loop where it checks the string for the ascii new line code, and then adds a "\n" or < br >. Or would something line adding " " around each line in text area, and then getting html to add < br > at each "?

But there must be some easier method of doing it? Any Ideas?

************UPDATED*********

Correct answer provided by @FastTurtle

Seems i was over complicating it.

n2lbr works perfect for my purpose.

Here is the updated PHP:

```
    &#60;Information&#62;
    <?php echo nl2br($_POST["Traceroute"]); ?> &#60;/Information&#62;
```

And here is the output now:

```
</Information>C:\Users\******>tracert 8.8.8.8

Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1 1 ms 3 ms 1 ms 192.168.0.1
2 12 ms 12 ms 8 ms **.**.**.**
3 9 ms 12 ms 9 ms **.**.**.**
4 13 ms 13 ms 13 ms example-doman.name [**.**.**.**]
5 15 ms 15 ms 14 ms example-doman.name [**.**.**.**]
6 12 ms 14 ms 13 ms **.**.**.**
7 14 ms 13 ms 16 ms **.**.**.**
8 11 ms 19 ms 15 ms google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]

Trace complete. </Information>
```

Comment: Hint: Whitespace ***in HTML*** doesn't mean anything by default...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
echo nl2br($_POST["Traceroute"]);
```

more on nl2br function http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Well....now i feel very silly! as the nl2br worked fine for my purpose. Not sure why i coudln't have got it working before. Think i've just been looking at it too long and over complicating it in my head :)

Thanks a lot @FastTurtle. I'll mark it as answered.